# Лендинг, php скрипт отправки почты

Tags: php, javascript, html

Возник вопрос как реализовать правильно функционал.

У меня имеется страница html с формой.

```
<div class="inner cover">
        <form role="form" action="send.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ФИО</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Укажите ФИО" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Телефон</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Укажите телефон" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Отправить</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Файл send.php содержит тестовый код:

```
<?php
  $fio = $_POST['fio'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  $fio = htmlspecialchars($fio);
  $telephone = htmlspecialchars($telephone);
  $fio = urldecode($fio);
  $telephone = urldecode($telephone);
  $fio = trim($fio);
  $telephone = trim($telephone);

  mail("mail@example.com", "Заявка с сайта", "ФИО:".$fio.". Телефон: ".$telephone ,"From: mail@example.com \r\n");
```

readfile('index.html')?>

При нажатии на отправить, url c host:/    меняется на host:/send.php

Как избавиться от этого перехода?

Я вижу решение в виде написания js, который по нажатию на "отправить" пошлет post запрос в send.php, который вернет в свою очередь json и на странице отображу результат операции (пока уведомления не прописывал).

Может есть более нормальные варианты? Как будет лучше реализовать данную идею?

Comment: Сделайте редирект обратно на `/`.

Comment: @u_mulder Так. Почитал про редирект. Хороший вариант. Тогда реализуется отправка письма, но останемся на странице.
А как можно будет реализовать с вариантом ответом об успешности\ошибки отправки, но остаться так же на данной странице?

Comment: Сессионная переменная.

Comment: @u_mulder хм.Вариант. Тогда оформи как ответ, зачту его. ) Спасибо. С:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **form** не указывать:

```
action="send.php"
```

Решить можно через ajax:

```
$('.btn-default').on('click',function(){
    let in_1 = $('input[name="fio"]').val();
    let in_2 = $('input[name="telephone"]').val();
    $.post(url,{fio:in_1,tel:in_2},function(data){ 
     //do something
    });
});
```

Как то так)

Отловить нажатие кнопки:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    // do somthing
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже как из одних вариантов решения. Но там человек написал как на php вывезти. Так что ток плюсик смогу поставить за полезный ответ. С:

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA а смысл? Ты выполнил ajax запрос и делай со странице всё что угодно. Конечно если тебе нужна супер пупер безопасность то надо перезагружать. и тогда просто не указывай action="send.php" . А в php  отлови нажатие кнопки.

Comment: Как отловить нажатие кнопки написал в ответе.

Comment: Честно, не знаю почему торкнуло сделать на чистом php. Но ваш вариант реализации и правда хороший. Скорее всего его и сделаю.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA рад помочь)